# Scala match on generic type

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

is it possible to match somehow on the return type A and if it is e.g. an int, do a calculation that returns an int.
See the following example:

```
def test[A](a: A):A = a match{
    case b: Int => b * 5
    case _ => a
}
```

The error message:

```
type mismatch;  found   : Int  required: A
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change return to `Any`

```
def test[A](a: A):Any = a match{
  case b: Int => b * 5
  case _ => a
}
```

another alternative is to do instanceof

`case b: Int => (b * 5).asInstanceOf[A]`

Comment: _Why_ doesn't OP's code compile? That is, _why_ can't scala tell that in the first case, `A` is `Int`, so it's okay to return `Int`? It seems like scala _should_ be able to tell. I suspect the reason is something do with runtime vs compiletime type checking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
def test(a : Int) = a * 5
def test[A](a : A) = a
```

Scala supports overloading methods and type-based dispatch, so in this case you don't have to resort to pattern matching.

Comment: `test(3)` and `test(3.asInstanceOf[Any])` would result in different functions used, even though in the second case it's also an `Int`.

Comment: That's true, but otherwise the return type is not statically determined from the argument type.